# Problems with Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to understand this code. It made for a ex-developer in my company, but really I don't understand so well how it works... If someone could help me, I will apreciate it.

```
var main= function(arr, fun) {
     var i= 0,
         max= arr.length,
         array= [];
     for (; i< max; i++) {
       array.push(fun(arr[i]));
     }
     return array;
};
```

Comment: It is just a loop where things get pushed to an Array.

Comment: Do you understand JavaScript in general and just not this,  do you just want to understand this part so that you can see how JavaScript works (you don't really understand JavaScript), or some other reason?

Comment: where is `fun` function ?

Comment: @Tushar: In the function signature

Comment: @TusharGupta: in the push line it is used.

Comment: Have you tried it? Obviously, `arr` is an array, like `[1, 2, 3]`.  Obviously, `fun` is another function, and since this function pushes its results onto an array, `fun` must return a value.  Try it and see.

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @EricJablow: never assume that they understand _anything_.

Comment: The main problem was that I don't understand what is the fun() function. The rest I understood, but that function confused me. So it's just a function that copy the array in a new array...thanks!

Comment: @user2528601 nobody knows what fun() is (well, a function, but we can't know more), cause it is a parameter. That function could return a value, an array, an object... it is a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's essentially a very obscure `Array.prototype.map` implementation. Personally I'd suggest this:

```
function array_map(arr,callback) {
    if( arr.map) return arr.map(callback);
    for( var i=0, l=arr.length, ret = []; i<l; i++) {
        ret[i] = callback(arr[i],i,arr);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It uses the browser's built-in function if it exists, and manually simulates it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can understand it well if you treat the argument "fun" as a function name. Your code just return the result of array "arr" after running as the "fun"'s input argument.

As following shows:

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2];
function fun( arg ) {
    return arg + 1;
}
```

In my mind, call your code like this:

```
main(arr, fun);
```

It should return:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Of course, I have not check it if it's really correct, you may take a test~

good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
var main= function(arr, fun) {
    //intialing variables
     var i= 0,
         max= arr.length,
         array= [];

    //looping the variables
     for (; i< max; i++) {
         //push values in to array after using the function passed
       array.push(fun(arr[i]));
     }
     return array;
};

//to test I have defined a function which adds 1
var res = main([1,2,3], function(val) {return val + 1});

alert(res);
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3WtE/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var main = function(arr, fun) {
     var i = 0, //starting a loop through the array at 0
         max = arr.length, //getting the number of items in the array
         array= []; //declaring a new array
     for (; i< max; i++) { //this is a loop that goes through all the values in the array
       array.push(fun(arr[i])); //this adds the values to the new array, using the function 'fun' to change the value
     }
     return array; //this returns the array
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It creates a new array by putting the results from a previous array `arr` for a function `fun` into the new array.

For instance, if `fun` gets the square of a number and `arr` is [1, 2, 3], `main` will return [1, 4, 9]

Answer (score 0):

It creates a function called `main`. This function takes an array and a handler function `fun` as parameters. It provides each element of the array to `fun` function and it adds the result of this call (`fun(arr[i]`)) to a new `array`. For example, the following use of the main function returns an array `{2, 3, 4, 5}`.

```
main({1, 2, 3, 4}, function(item) {
    return item + 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's split the code:

```
// will create a function which accepts 2 parameters
var main= function(arr, fun) {

//variable declaration
var i= 0,
max= arr.length,  // get array length
array= [];       // create new array

// add function value (fun(arr[i])) to an array. arr is a parameter which is also an array
// fun(arr[i]) is a callback function which accepts 1 parameter (array one)
for (; i< max; i++) {
   array.push(fun(arr[i]));
}

// return the new array
 return array;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a strategy for dealing with unfamiliar constructs. Asking a blanket question on Stackoverflow may help in the short term, but probably doesn't strengthen your interpretation "muscles".

I'd suggest first ensuring that you can run the code in a debugger and set a breakpoint at the first line of code in the function. Then use the debugger to answer questions such as:

1). What comes in? What are the types of the arguments.

2). What is returned

You then notice that fun is actually a function. So from where is your function called? What functions are passed as that second argument.

You might then be wondering about some construct you've not seen before, for example what array.push() does. So a quick google answers that.

Suddenly you understand and have exercised you "muscles". And if you are still confused you probably have a much better, more precise question to ask here.

Comment: You are right, I know that post here the problem is not the better solution, but I needed "quick", of corse I usally don't do that because I also want to learn. Thanks for your comment